# Disk Partitioning while installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: partitioning

I am an absolute beginner in Linux and I have problems with partitioning my disk space while installing Ubuntu 12.04. I have 300 GB of unallocated space on my hard disk. How can I divide the available space? My music collection is almost 170 GB and how can I make space for these music files (Like D: drive in Windows)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/280270/partitions-required-for-installing-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Recommended Partitioning Scheme](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/apcs03.html) for new users from Ubuntu.com