# Ubuntu Partition/Dual-Boot HELP!

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I recently got a PC with Windows 8 pre-installed. It has a 1TB HDD and 24GB SSD. So I decided to dual-boot with Ubuntu, using the simple method ("Install Ubuntu beside W8"). However, the only disk space that popped up for the partition to be made was the SSD, which I assumed I could use just to install the Ubuntu OS. Now, when running Ubuntu it says there is not enough room for files and things. 
I then went and partitioned my HDD for 250GB space to use for Ubuntu (now unallocated) but I have no idea how to make Ubuntu use that free space for the necessary files instead of the SSD. If I restart the Ubuntu installation, will it work (select "manual setup" and then pick the HDD) or will it see that I already have Ubuntu on the SSD and not allow me to set it up? 
Is there any way to keep the Ubuntu on the SSD and then set up the 250GB HDD partition to use for files? Or any way to move the Ubuntu to the HDD instead of the SSD?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partitions required for Installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280270/partitions-required-for-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Install Ubuntu beside Windows 8," select the option called "Something Else." This will enable you to manually specify your partitions. See [this page](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/) for details (scroll down to step #7-C). (This guide refers to Ubuntu 11.10, but I'm pretty sure there haven't been huge changes in the intervening releases.)