# Disk Partitioning Issue

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning

I am very new to Linux (Ubuntu) and to be hones this is the 6th. time I am re-installing Ubuntu in a week as I always encounter one or the other issue with the installation. I would like to have a good suggestion on Disk Partitioning and other configuration to run it smoothly.

I am using Lenovo G570 laptop with 8gig of ram, Intel® Core™ i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4, Intel® Sandybridge Mobile. Radeom Graphics and 500 gigs of HD. I have downloaded ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso and ready to put it to my pen driver to start re-installing.

I am more concerned about the performance and stability.

Comment: plz explain clearly that how much space did you want to allocate for ubuntu and for other drives?

Comment: I want to install only Ubuntu on my laptop so the entire 500GB will be using for Ubuntu.

Comment: so what's your actual question?

Comment: I have a single disk drive of 500GB so what will be the good partitions for better performance. like /home, /, /boot, etc. ?

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/280270/partitions-required-for-installing-ubuntu

Comment: It isn't clear from your question why you are even worried about it and wouldn't just take the defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I'll do
make two partitions, one to store data and other for Ubuntu as you have 500 gig make 400 gig for data and leave 100 gig unpartitioned 
now start installation and choose to install it in unpartisioned space.  Ubuntu will select the recommended partition format depending on your hardware

The above one is simple but if you want to manually partition then make a partition home folder, one for swap(9gig) and one for the system

Answer (score 0):

http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony. this might help u decide. better to create 3 partitions.one for windows. one for ur general data and one for ubuntu. split the ubuntu partiton into 2. one for swap equal to ur ram and the rest for ur install.